# How to imitate "cut -d: -f2" with sed? ("(.*):(.*):" matching too many fields)

Tags: regex, sed, cut, regex-greedy

Just to be clear: I am testing my code on /etc/passwd.
I am trying to cut second column from text with sed (it's an exercise from my teacher, that's why I'm not using anything else).
I tried using

```
sed 's/\(.*\):\(.*\):\(.*\)/\2/' /etc/passwd
```

but it's cutting the next to last column, probably because sed is taking all characters until it finds two last ":". How can i cut second column without specifying how many of them will be in file?

Comment: `'s/^[^:]*:\([^:]*\).*/\1/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you identified, `.*` can match any number of characters, including `:`s.

`[^:]*`, by contrast, matches *everything except* a `:`, so it isn't prone to this.

As Wiktor points out in comments, then:

```
sed -Ee 's/^([^:]*):([^:]*):.*/\2/' <<<'one:two:three:four'
```

...correctly returns `two`.